# extern const struct VS struct extern const

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider:

flavor1.h

```
extern const struct X {
    int i = 1;
} x;
```

flavor2.h

```
struct Y {
    int i = 1;
} extern const y;
```

impl.cpp

```
#include "flavor1.h"
#include "flavor2.h"

const X x;
const Y y;
```

If I try to compile : **'const Y y' : redéfinition** (redefinition) - even tho `y` is declared `extern`.

My question : what am I actually declaring in `flavor2.h` ? I thought it would be equivalent to `flavor1.h`.

Comment: Much easier to deal with: `struct X { ... }; inline const/*expr*/ X x;` `struct Y { ... }; inline const/*expr*/ Y y;`

Comment: Why is the `extern` in `extern const y;` ignored tho? (I admit i'm not familiar with `inline`).

Comment: It is probably complaining because of `const extern const`.  If something has already been declared as `const` would `const`ing it again normally produce an error?

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jG3KqeePj). As including headers just means inserting their content directly it shouldn't matter that I dropped these.

Comment: @cup the error raised is "redefinition (y)" which means the "extern" keyword was ignored in "flavor2.h" (for some reason).

Comment: @cup Where do you see `const extern const`?

Comment: @Aconcagua it must be a MSVC thing then *shrug*

Comment: Sorry - my bad - not reading the code correctly.

Comment: @PinkTurtle Indeed, MSVC fails on godbolt as well. No reference to the standard, but as far as I am aware the storage class specifier should, just like `const`, be able to trail the type as well (and clang, too, agrees on), so I'd assume a (yet another) MSVC bug…

Comment: A "redefiniton error" has nothing to do with `const` or `extern`. It simply means you didn't put include guards or `#pragma once` in your header.

Comment: @JanSchultke I think you've misread the question and it should be reopened. This has nothing to do with include guards. The program will still have the same behavior if written in a single source file. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8TbM69nso). Notice that msvc only gives error in the demo while gcc and clang compiles the program. Also, the duplicate target you closed with is wrong duplicate because in the duplicate post, the OP is defining classes with **same name** but here, the name of the classes **is different**. So this should be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in MSVC.

Your code is valid. As you are saying, there is only one definition of `y`. The first declaration of `y` is not a definition because of the use of `extern`.

GCC and Clang also don't have a problem with the code.

And yes, the order of the decl-spcifiers `extern`, `const` and `struct X { int i = 1; }` in the declaration should not matter. They can be ordered in any way you like.